# Prove that $\overline{A \times B}=\overline{A} \times \overline{B}$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

How I can prove that $\overline{A \times B}=\overline{A} \times \overline{B}$?

---

I start proving that $\overline{A} \times \overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A \times B}$. 
Taking $(x,y) \in \overline{A} \times \overline{B},\ \ \ \forall U \times V \in \mathscr{N}_{(x,y)}$, 
$x \in \overline{A} \Rightarrow U\cap A \not= \emptyset \ $  and $\ y \in \overline{B} \Rightarrow V\cap  B\not= \emptyset \ $ so 
$U \times V \cap A \times B \not= \emptyset \Rightarrow (x,y) \in \overline{A \times B}$

---

Is this part correct? And how can I prove the other part?

Comment: It is correct, maybe you should justify why is enough to only check the sets of the form $U\times V$. To prove the other inclusion, try to prove that the product of closed sets is closed in the product topology, then it will be enough because $\overline{A}\times\overline{B}$ will be a closed set containing $A\times B$ and hence it will contain $\overline{A\times B}$.

Comment: @User 487, Notice that, it is still true for arbitrary product. See Theorem 19.5 Topology by Munkers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part is correct, but you could use more words and fewer symbols: let $(x,y) \in \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$. To see that $(x,y) \in \overline{A \times B}$, we take a *basic* open open neighbourhood of $(x,y)$, so one of the form $U \times V$ where $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ and $V$ an open neighbourhood of $y$ and show it intersects $A \times B$: as $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ and $x \in \overline{A}$ we know that there is some $a \in A \cap U$ and similarly, as $y \in \overline{B}$ we have some $b \in B \cap V$, but then $(a,b) \in (A \times B) \cap (U \times V) \neq \emptyset$ and we're done.

For the reverse, we take $(x,y) \in \overline{A \times B}$ and we will show that $x \in \overline{A}$ and $y \in \overline{B}$, so that $(x,y) \in \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$, showing the inclusion.

To see that $x \in \overline{A}$: let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$. Then $U \times Y$ is an open neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ so the assumption that $(x,y) \in \overline{A \times B}$ gives us $(a,b) \in (U \times Y) \cap (A \times B)$. In particular we have that $a \in U \cap A \neq \emptyset$. As $U$ was arbitrary, we have that $x \in \overline{A}$ as claimed. To show that $y \in \overline{B}$ is similar and left to the reader, using sets of the form $X \times V$ instead.

As an alternative to that last proof, note that $$\overline{A} \times \overline{B} = \pi_X^{-1}[\overline{A}] \cap \pi_Y^{-1}[\overline{B}]$$
where $\pi_X$ and $\pi_Y$ are the continuous projections so that $\overline{A} \times \overline{B}$ is closed in $X \times Y$. It obviously contains $A \times B$ so also $\overline{A \times B}$, by minimality of the closure.